# How to have dropdown in simple_form_for with options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was using form_for till now and was having this code

```
<%= f.select :name, options_for_select(%w[Mike Nick Jason Tim]) %>
```

but what is the equivalent of this in simple_form_for ? I looked at the github doc of simple_form_for but they have not covered this

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The doc covers this topic, take a look at `Collections` section

```
<%= f.input :name, :collection => %w[Mike Nick Jason Tim] %>
```

Comment: thanks, just wondering, how to get two words as an option ? as "John Smith" is not working but only [John Smith] which are two different options ?

Comment: Escape space with backslash,`%w(Mike\ Nick Jason Tim) => ["Mike Nick", "Jason", "Tim"]`